# When i create subclass of NSManagedObject, I am getting 'failed code with exit 1'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, compiler-errors

When I create subclass of `NSManagedObject` in Swift,Xcode 8.1(using *editor-->Create* `NSManagedObject` sub class)

I am getting compiler error as below

`Command /Applications/Xcode copy.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Comment: search for duplicate files in your project with same name and keep the only file you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to .xcmodeld file, go to datamodel inspector
change the codegen to manual/None

If it doesnot work, delete the model and recreate it and then change codegen propety then it wll work.